# What is the purpose of declaring variables in a class

Tags: php, oop

What is the purpose of declaring a variable at the top of a class if it works without it?

```
class Testclass
{
    public $testvar = "default value";

    public function setTestvar($testvar) { 
        $this->testvar = $testvar; 
    }

    public function getTestvar() { 
        return $this->testvar; 
    }
}
```

compared to:

```
class Testclass
{
    public function setTestvar($testvar) { 
        $this->testvar = $testvar; 
    }

    public function getTestvar() { 
        return $this->testvar; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the same topic [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115115/implicit-class-variable-declaration-in-php) PHP is really a lightweight language

Comment: maybe interesting? [When To Declare Properties Of A Class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249230/when-to-declare-properties-of-a-class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both variants are correct but the second one is lacking when getting `testvar` before you initialize it.

If you call `$test->getTestvar();` before you set it with `$test->setTestval('bla bla');`, you will get a warning, something like:

> **Notice**:  Undefined property: Testclass::$testvar

The second variant also lacks the property visibility part (i.e. private, protected). [More about visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).

The declaration of class properties above methods is a good practice, it's taken from strict oop-languages like java.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP there is no functional purpose to including the declaration.  It seems that you have read up on the documentation and you are 100% correct.

*There is one case however.  If we call the* `getter` *before setting the variable, we will get an `undefined variable` exception.*

Now let's think about this.

Let's say I am a programmer, specialized in c++ and java.  I'm a pro at those languages (so I pick up PHP pretty quick), and your company just hired me to help work on the web application you are working on.  I take a look at this object, and have no clue what's going on.

Really what it comes down to is that PHP is one of the weirdest languages I know.  You have stumbled across just one of many odd things that PHP does.  This will not be your last.  Objects are templates; they are pieces of code that programmers can use for a variety of reasons.  The more information and formatting that we can do when making the object, the more effectively it can be used by other programmers.  *Its the exact same reason as to why we format our code.*

***TL;DR***

No reason, besides documentation, ease of reading, and avoiding Undeclared Variables.

### Edit

*Another important issue was brought up*

Declaring variables in the global context allows you to set your properties visibility.  Public or Private.  Because you have getters and setters I am assuming that your properties are private.  So you need to declare that.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense about consistency across languages as well.

Comment: I'd add ide auto-completing, but that's pretty minor and personal

Comment: You didn't mention property visibility in your answer, which can be seen as a "functional purpose" of property declaration