# Declaring class variables question

Tags: php

What do these var declarations actually do inside of a PHP class:

```
class VbForumsPageMain extends BxDolPageView {
    var $_oMain;
    var $_oTemplate;
    var $_oConfig;
    var $_oDb;

    function VbForumsPageMain(&$oMain) {
        $this->_oMain = &$oMain;
        $this->_oTemplate = $oMain->_oTemplate;
        $this->_oConfig = $oMain->_oConfig;
        $this->_oDb = $oMain->_oDb;
        parent::BxDolPageView('vb_forums_main');
    }
}
```

Are they neccessary and do they add any extra use to the variables?  I'm not sure whey they're in the class twice.

Comment: what do you mean by "twice" ?

Comment: I presume your first programming language is PHP?

Comment: His first OOP exposure at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **first use is defining** them, the **second is initialising** them. It's **good practice to define them up front** and **even better practice to [set the appropriate visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)**.

Have a read of the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for more information - what you learn now will put you in good stead for the future.

Comment: +1, good response. Also want to add [another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086494/when-should-i-declare-variables-in-a-php-class) for reference purposes for the OP.

Comment: So using var is an older practice that isn't necessary anymore?

Comment: @whatshakin Effectively. In modern code, you'd simply use the appropriate public/protected/private visibility. (That said, if you require PHP 4 compatibility, stick with plain old "var".)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here, hope it helps - [What does PHP keyword 'var' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206105/what-does-php-keyword-var-do).

It basically declares public properties or the class, but you should use `private`, `public` and `protected` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are needed as they define the extension of the class.
The *VbForumsPageMain* class has the same properties (variables) as the *BxDolPageView* extended by those *vars*.
The function below sets the values and the structure of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to other answers: These definitions at the beginning of the class are very important to auto-competition in IDEs. If you don't define the properties at the beginning, the IDE might give you "undefined property" errors. Furthermore it gives you a quick overview of which properties are available in a class.