# Can I use a variable without declaring by $this->myvar in php?

Tags: php, variables

In the following code, variables user and permissions are not declared at the beginning like $data, $module etc. And these $this->user and $this->permissions are used in the extended class of this class.

My question is can I use variables without declaring and using $this->myvar?

Thanks in advance.

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

// Deprecated: No longer used globally
protected $data;
public $module;
public $controller;
public $method;

public function MY_Controller()
{
      .......
     $this->user = $this->ion_auth->get_user();
     .........
     // List available module permissions for this user
    $this->permissions = $this->user ? 
     $this->permission_m->get_group($this->user->group_id) : array();
```

Comment: Related Questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115115/implicit-class-variable-declaration-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086494/when-should-i-declare-variables-in-a-php-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can.

PHP automatically creates public properties when initially set, eg

```
class MyClass
{
    private $foo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->bar = 'bar'; // Now contains "public $bar"
    }
}
```

The only time this differs is if you have a magic `__set($name, $value)` method which will catch an attempt to write to an undefined or non-visible (in the current scope) property.

Comment: @shin I would have expected to see it mentioned [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) but it's not. I guess it's just one of these things you pick up

Answer (score -1):

Yes !

Maybe this send a 'warning message', you can use ini_set('display_errors', 0) to avoid it.