# Why does a PHP object accept members that were only mentioned when called?

Tags: php, oop

I am in a paradox with the following code snippet and I am not sure what to call it.

I have defined a very simple class which has no variable yet. Now, in the constructor, I am accepting an array of keys and values and assigning variables on the fly like this, using a foreach loop:

```
class Food{

    function Food($construct){
        foreach($construct as $key=>$value){
            $this->$key = $value;
        }

    }


}
```

If I created an instance now with the input like so:

```
$food = new Food(array('name' => 'chicken' , 'unit' => 'kg' , 'calorie' => 10000));
```

I would have got:

```
var_dump($food);    
object(Food)[1]
  public 'name' => string 'chicken' (length=7)
  public 'unit' => string 'kg' (length=2)
  public 'calorie' => int 10000
```

How is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible in PHP and is the default implementation unless you have stated otherwise (via __get() and __set()). Creating public members on the fly is possible only for the current instance, it does not create it for the class overall. And it's possible from inside the class or from outside (e.g. via the instance).

```
$food->smth = 100;
```

will create `public smth`

An empty `__set()` magic method can prevent this behavior

```
public function __set($name, $value) { }
```

For the second question:

It is not safe and using public members at all is not safe (unless you have really good reason for exposing your properties). The convention says you have to have mostly private/protected members with accessors for them. So you can have the controll for the class from inside the class rather than from the instance of it. And for many other reasons, including code reusability.

Comment: It's weird, but cannot find any documentation about possibility of dynamically define new property for any object.

Comment: @sectus me neither :p

Comment: @sectus it is a result of the dynamic variable definition in the whole language. It is not documented in the OOP section, because it's not certainly related to it, but it's documented in variables section http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php  `It is not necessary to initialize variables in PHP however it is a very good practice. `

Comment: The slight difference between objects and procedural style is that procedural programming does not have more than one context. Assigning value to a variable in one page makes variable defined for the whole page. (excluding functions, but yet can be accessed via global)

Comment: @RoyalBg , so there nothing about that $object->var could be treated as simple variable.

Comment: @sectus not quite, in your global context, if you do not violate the principle that $object should be object, and its representation should allow it, then, $object->var will be variable in globalspace. However, it still affects the instance. To be honest, not sure if I understood your statement/question :)

Comment: @RoyalBg , I know about this feature. But documentation has no description of it at all. I would like to answer the question, but did not find mention of this behavior in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

That variable isn't uninitialized, it's just undeclared.

Declaring variables in a class definition is a point of style for readability. Plus you can set accessibility (private or public).

Anyway, declaring variables explicitly has nothing to do with OOP, it's programming-language-specific. In Java you can't do that because variables must be declared explicitly.

reference - `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1086494/when-should-i-declare-variables-in-a-php-class`